# Generate random numbers from a Skellam Distribution

Tags: c, distribution, poisson

In my current code I generate two numbers (x and y) from Poisson distributions and then I substract y from x. These two operations represent almost 50% of the total computation time of my simulations!

I just discovered on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) that the substraction of two indepoendent Poisson distributions is a Skellam distribution. I am hoping to gain computation time by asking C to draw only one random number from a Skellam distribution rather than two numbers from two different Poissons distributions.

- Can I indeed gain computation time this way?
- Is there a efficient algorithm for drawing a random number from a Skellam distribution in C?

Comment: Maybe your Poisson distribution calculation can be optimized instead?

Comment: Since a Skellam distribution draws on two independant Poisson distributions, I suspect you need to ask a mathematician.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am pretty much using the `rpois` function from R. Someone gave me this code and I have been told that it is very performant.

Comment: I very doubt that you can gain anything since the probability mass function is very complicated in comparison to poisson's. I sense your algorithm is one of the most efficient ways.

Comment: This [page](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/skellam/html/skellam.html) about a function named `rskellam()` states that `rskellam` is calculated as `rpois(n,lambda1)-rpois(n,lambda2) `. If you are using `rpois(1,lambda)` many times, it might be better to compute `rpois(n,lambda)` with n>1 and store the result in a buffer...My guess is that it is already the case and i am not sure about this being a good advice.

Comment: I think I got the answer I needed through your comment. Thank you. Is one of you willing to write a short answer from your comments?